# Is there a way to show an if statement in a UML Sequence Diagram?

Tags: uml, standards, sequence-diagram

I went on an interview last year and was shown a sequence diagram and was asked to describe the the sequence. There were 2 things in the diagram I had never seen before. I asked what one of them was and was told that's how an if statement is shown in a sequence diagram. The other was an arrow going back to the actor that originated the arrow, I assumed that was a loop.

1. Is there a standard way to show a conditional sequence?
2. How often is a conditional sequence used in UML sequence diagrams?

Comment: UML 2.0? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/3101.html

Comment: If you start wanting to put conditions in sequence diagrams, your sequence diagrams are probably two complex.  Generally, you create a diagram for the "Happy Path" and *maybe* a couple for common error cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Is there a standard way to show a conditional sequence?

Yes. You can use the If else condition, also called alternatives in UML terms.

2.How often is a conditional sequence used in UML sequence diagrams?
Every time there is the need to explain the choice between two or more message sequences.

You can read more about it [here](http://creately.com/diagram-type/article/understanding-basics-sequence-diagrams)